# How do you choose the exact width for PMOS/NMOS in your design?

Tags: integrated-circuit, nmos, pmos

I'm designing the following function:
$$F = ((A'+B) \times (A+B'))'$$
This is the schematic:

[image]

Now I know that in general PMOS width has to be 2-3 times that of NMOS width. But how do you decide exactly what width in the first place? I know there are considerations to keep in mind such as the area, rise and fall times, current etc.

Do we simply pick a value for NMOS and make PMOS 2-3+ times of that then play around with it to optimize the performance as required? If its more complicated than that, then what parameters do I need to know in order to calculate the width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depend on the target rise time, fall rime, power, Cload.

1. Begin with min W and min length of NMOS and make PMOS 2-3+ times of that.
2. Simulation with your cap. load

--> RESULT: **rise time, fall time, power** --> Match your target  or not? After that, you can make decision for design with some of changing of device size.

3. Sometime, **logical effort method** will help you make decision how many stages of your circuit. But this method will take time for calculation.

Example:

- Block function --> connect cap. load.
- Block function --> inverter 1x --> cap. Load
- Block function --> inverter 1x ---> inverter 2x --> cap. Load.

Hope it help you.